# what is wmaxima doing here?

Tags: partial-derivative, maxima-software

there is a problem in the calculus book I'm reading that has a function f (see below) that is not continuous at (0,0).  the book says that despite this fact, both partial derivatives still exist there.  so i am trying to use wmaxima to prove the existence of just fx for now. So i go through the motions and wmaxima gives me an answer that appears to be validate, but I don't understand the answer.  so I'm not convinced.  I think I'm missing some key point either in how maxima takes derivatives and evaluates them, or in my understanding of partial derivatives. I'm not sure which.

[image: Maxima session]

edit: oops.  i try to get a better quality picture for you.

edit: here is the actual problem I'm trying to solve.

[image: Problem from book]

Comment: Could you please post the question here. The picture is very small and quite difficult to read.

Comment: maybe wmaxima assumes that any fraction with a numerator will be zero & gives that as an output before reading the rest?

Comment: Thanks for improving the picture. Note $f_{x} = \frac{y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ as you got before and $f_{y} = \frac{x(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ by symmetry. However, choose $y = kx$. Then $f(x,y) = \frac{2kx^2}{(1+k^2)x^2} = \frac{2k}{1+k^2}$. So, for $k=0$ and $k=1$, we have that $f(0,0) = 0$ and $1$; a contradiction. The point is we can choose $(x,0)$ and $(x,x)$ in any delta neighbourhood, but $f(x,0) = 0$ and $f(x,x) = 1$, whence there is no limit.

Comment: Chris K - hi, yes I understand that the limit does not exist for f(x,y).  that very explanation you give is in the book.  this problem is an extension of that problem.  it is saying that despite this fact, fx and fy do exist at (0,0).  that is what I don't understand.  why do they exist?  I don't get that part.  so I try to have wmaxima explain that to me.  it gives me zero for fx, which is a valid answer and supports what the book says, but I don't understand why it is zero and not undefined.

Comment: @olive euler - that is a thought, but I don't think that is the case because i did some reading in the help section of the program and it makes a distinction between 'serial' verses 'parallel' substitutions and the "at" command that I am using uses the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the xMaxima behaviour (perhaps having produced an error with parallel substitution, it then tries serial substitution to try to get an error-free answer).

The original point about the partial derivative is that $g(x)=f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$ and so is continuous including at $x=0$, and has a partial derivative with respect to $x$ of $0$.  So $f(x,y)$ has a partial derivative everywhere of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{y(y^2-x^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ except when $y=0$ where it is $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 $.

You can make a similar statement about $h(y)=f(0,y)=0$ and so  $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

Comment: I'm not sure why `at` behaves the way it does either, but `ev` correctly complains `expt: undefined: 0 to a negative exponent`